# Decode h264 video frame from bytes received from a WebSocket

Tags: python, video, websocket, decode, frame

I'm trying to get frames from my home security camera (Provision-ISR).

So, I see when I open the web client, that the video frames are sent in a WebSocket.

I copy one of the frames,and I try to save it to file, but it's not working.

```
import numpy as np

from cv2 import cv2

frame_buffer = np.frombuffer(bytearray(frame), np.int16,int(len(frame) / 2))

cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",frame_buffer)
```

this is example of the hex editor

[image]

Comment: What does “it’s not works” mean‽ What exactly did you do and what was the result?

Comment: I try to save this data(bytes) in a file,the image file is wierd,1*3868

Comment: You'll need to provide more concrete details here, not merely your interpretation of what's happening.

Comment: I added new details..see the picture that i get from the frame

Comment: Your bytes view is useless. It needs to be hex values. Save the file bytes that you receive as a file like `test.bin` then open that binary in a **hex editor** to see the byte values properly and then also copy/paste then into your question. Or just share a link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
`av.open(rawData, format="h264", mode='r')` - do the decode

```
def save_banch_of_frames(rawData):
    global count
    rawData.seek(0)
    container = av.open(rawData, format="h264", mode='r')
    for packet in container.demux():
        if packet.size == 0:
            continue
        for frame in packet.decode():
            cv2.imwrite(f"frames/file{count}.jpg", frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24"))
            count += 1

def check_is_keyframe(frame):
    frameData = io.BytesIO()
    frameData.write(frame)
    frameData.seek(0)
    container = av.open(frameData, format="h264", mode='r')
    for packet in container.demux():
        if packet.is_keyframe:
            return True
    return False


data = get_frame_from_response(video_socket)
    while True:
        rawData = io.BytesIO()
        is_keyframe = False

        while not is_keyframe:
            rawData.write(data)
            data = get_frame_from_response(video_socket)
            is_keyframe = check_is_keyframe(data)
        save_banch_of_frames(rawData)
```